# Routing wrong access the action

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

By default for URL routing in MVC is **{controller}/{action}/{id}**. Then we can access mydomain.com/Products/Details/1 and etc.

Now, I have register another map route I called **CategoryLandingPage**.

```
routes.MapRoute(
name: "CategoryLandingPage",
url: "category",
defaults: new { controller = "Category", action = "Index" });
```

So it will show all the category in the page.

Then I register another map route called CategoryDetails

```
routes.MapRoute(
name: "CategoryDetails", 
url: "category/{categoryName}", 
defaults: new { controller = "Category", action = "Details", categoryName = UrlParameter.Optional });
```

When somebody access **mydomain.com/category/cars**, it will show all the products with related to the cars.

Same controller also have **another actions such Create,Edit,Delete, and more**.

The problems is,When I access **mydomain.com/category/create** it will go to the **Details action**. It not go to the create action in Category Contoller.

How can I solved this matter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two ways:

Either use a [Route Constraint](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/controllers-and-routing/creating-a-custom-route-constraint-cs) to ensure the {categoryName} part is a match for one of your categories:

```
//You will have to make this
var categoryRouteConstraint = new CategoryRouteConstraint();

routes.MapRoute(
name: "CategoryDetails", 
url: "category/{categoryName}", 
constraints: new { categoryName = categoryRouteConstraint }
defaults: new { controller = "Category", action = "Details", categoryName = UrlParameter.Optional });
```

Example route constraint:

```
public class CategoryRouteConstraint : IRouteConstraint
    {
        public bool Match(HttpContextBase httpContext, Route route, string parameterName, RouteValueDictionary values, RouteDirection routeDirection)
        {
            if (routeDirection == RouteDirection.UrlGeneration)
                return true;

            if (string.Equals(parameterName, "categoryName", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            {
                //return true if (string)values[parameterName] == "known category name"
            }

            return false;
        }
    }
```

Or, intercept the specific actions first:

```
routes.MapRoute(
name: "CategoryDetails", 
url: "category/create", 
defaults: new { controller = "Category", action = "Create", categoryName = UrlParameter.Optional });

routes.MapRoute(
name: "CategoryDetails", 
url: "category/delete", 
defaults: new { controller = "Category", action = "Delete", categoryName = UrlParameter.Optional });

//Do one for Edit, Delete

//CategoryDetails route after
routes.MapRoute(
name: "CategoryDetails", 
url: "category/{categoryName}", 
defaults: new { controller = "Category", action = "Details", categoryName = UrlParameter.Optional });
```

Comment: Seems like second solutions is the direct way, but for the first solution any effect on the performance?

Comment: If you use a cached dictionary-lookup of known categories to match against - it's normally fine. I use this approach and it's sub-milisecond

Answer (score 2):

While the answers above are correct, this is a simpler solution, although it will not dynamically update if you add actions to your controller as Dave's answer will.

As I understand it if {key} is an existing action you want it to be handled by the default route instead of using the Details action on the Category controller.

In order to achieve that you could list all the possible actions in the key constraint:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "CategoryDetails",
    url: "Category/{key}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Category", action = "Details" },
    constraints: new { key = @"[^create|update|delete]" }
);
```

In this example the `CategoryDetails` route will match only if the url is not `Category/create` or `Category/update` or `Category/delete`. For example ads/cars will match and use the `Details` action.

Comment: Isn't your code doing the opposite? Isn't it saying that CategoryDetails will match only when the key *is* create, update or delete?

Comment: I think you miss [ ] inside the actions name? I tried put that symbol and now it's working...

Comment: hmm.. I think it is still wrong. For example `car` will not match your regex. I'm not sure if it is even possible to do what you want. Check it here: http://regexr.com/3bctm

Comment: Wow, never thought about doing it like that - great stuff

Answer (score 0):

You can't thit in this way. You overrided default route by url: "category/{categoryName}"

Good way to solve the problem with routing is to name it like below:

- items/ - for list of elements
- items/{name_or_id}/details - to show details of element
- items/{name_or_id}/edit - to update element
- items/create - tu create a new element

For your case it can be:

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "CategoryLandingPage",
            url: "categories",
            defaults: new { controller = "Category", action = "Index" });

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "CategoryDetails",
            url: "categories/{categoryName}/details",
            defaults: new { controller = "Category", action = "Details" });

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "CategoryUpdate",
            url: "categories/{categoryName}/edit",
            defaults: new { controller = "Category", action = "Edit" });

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "CategoryLandingPage",
            url: "categories/create",
            defaults: new { controller = "Category", action = "Create" });
```